# Obter o menor número positivo que é divisível por todos os números de 1 a 20

Tags: python, matemática

Eu fiz um código de uma forma que funciona, mas não parece nada *pythônico*, e demora um monte de tempo.

```
i = 1
numero = 1
while i != 0:
    if numero % 1 == 0 and numero % 2 == 0 and numero % 3 == 0 and numero % 4 == 0 and numero % 5 == 0 and numero % 6 ==\
            0 and numero % 7 == 0 and numero % 8 == 0 and numero % 9 == 0 and numero % 10 == 0 and numero % 11 == 0\
              and numero % 12 == 0 and numero % 13 == 0 and numero % 14 == 0 and numero % 15 == 0 and numero % 16 == 0 \
              and numero % 17 == 0 and numero % 18 == 0 and numero % 19 == 0 and numero % 20 == 0:
        print(numero)
        i = 0
    else:
        numero += 1
```

Como poderia melhorar esse código?

Comment: Tem sim, é chamado de cálculo do MMC. Você consegue fazer em 20 passos e não precisa verificar divisibilidade em momento algum

Comment: Ou até menos passos, dado que se é múltiplo de qualquer valor par também será divisível por 2; se for múltiplo de 16 ele já será múltiplo de 8, 4 e 2; se for múltiplo de 15 já será também de 5 e 3, etc.

Comment: Não que vá deixar o algoritmo *muito* mais rápido, mas todo número é divisível por 1, então não precisa testar `numero % 1 == 0` :-)

Comment: Aqui você pode ter algumas ideias de algoritmos para implementar sem necessariamente fazê-lo pela forçq bruta: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/lcm.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No fundo o que você quer é calcular o MMC (mínimo múltiplo comum) entre esses números. Então é mais uma questão matemática do que *pythônica*. Basta considerar que:

1. para 3 números `x`, `y` e `z`, o `MMC(x, y, z)` é o mesmo que `MMC(MMC(x, y), z)` (que também é o mesmo que `MMC(x, MMC(y, z))`). Ou seja, podemos ir calculando o MMC de 2 em 2 números até chegar no resultado final
2. uma das muitas formas de calcular é `MMC(x, y) = x * y / MDC(x, y)` (sendo que MDC é o máximo divisor comum)

Até o Python 3.8 você pode usar a função [`math.gcd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) para calcular o MDC, então basta usá-la para calcular o passo 2. E para o passo 1, basta fazer um *loop* nos números e ir calculando o MMC entre eles:

```
from math import gcd

def mmc(numeros):
    m = 1
    for n in numeros:
        m = m * n // gcd(m, n)
    return m

numeros = range(2, 21)
print(mmc(numeros)) # 232792560
```

Eu usei `range(2, 21)` (todos os números entre 2 e 20), pois não faz sentido incluir o `1` (todos os números são múltiplos de 1 e é redundante incluí-lo no cálculo).

A partir do Python 3.9 você pode usar [`math.lcm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.lcm) para calcular o MMC diretamente, sem precisar da fórmula acima:

```
from math import lcm

print(lcm(*range(2, 21))) # 232792560
```

Detalhe que os números do `range` tem que ser passados via [*unpacking*](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (com o asterisco antes do `range`), para que os números sejam passados como parâmetros (sem o asterisco, o próprio `range` é passado como parâmetro e aí não funciona).

---

Claro que você pode otimizar um pouco mais, pois não precisa ter todos os números na lista. Poderia ser apenas:

```
###########################################
# Até Python 3.8
from math import gcd

def mmc(numeros):
    m = 1
    for n in numeros:
        m = m * n // gcd(m, n)
    return m

print(mmc([11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]))

###########################################
# A partir de Python 3.9
from math import lcm

print(lcm(11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)) # 232792560
```

Se o número é múltiplo de 20, com certeza também será múltiplo de 2, 4, 5 e 10, se for múltiplo de 18, com certeza também será de 2, 3, 6 e 9, e assim por diante. E como é múltiplo de 3 e 4, também será de 12, etc. Então não precisa ter todos na lista.

---

Outra opção é usar [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), que deixa o código mais curto (mas não necessariamente mais fácil de entender, *varia conforme a opinião de cada um)*:

```
from math import gcd
from functools import reduce

def mmc(numeros):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y // gcd(x, y), numeros)
```

Mas isso somente para Python <= 3.8 pois a partir da versão 3.9 basta passar todos os números para `math.lcm`, sem a necessidade de usar `reduce`.

Comment: Se quiser comparar os tempos de cada solução: https://repl.it/repls/InformalPowerlessBundledsoftware

Comment: Muito obrigado, foi muito útil sua contribuição.